# spring boot mongo querydsl with kotlin not generating meta data classes

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, querydsl

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.t1</groupId>
    <artifactId>t1example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>t1</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.21</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                                    <classifier>jpa</classifier>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Record.kt

```
package com.t1.mmkqe.entity
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document

@Document(collection = "Record")
data class Record(
        @Id val name: String = ""
)
```

It does not generate Q classes.
But if use JPA @Entity annotation, it does.
I try many variants with pom/gradle, different versions and try many examples from internet, but without success.

Perhaps it impossible.

Comment: What is the issue you're having and what is the expected output?

Comment: Querydsl must generate file \target\generated-sources\kapt\compile\com\t1\mmkqe\entity\QRecord.java
  

`@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer")  public class QRecord extends EntityPathBase<Record> {  
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1455667927L;  public static final QRecord record = new QRecord("record");
  
...`
  

If i change Record.kt (change @Document to @Entity):  `@Entity data class Record(@Id val name: String = "")`  
  
it works

Comment: Can you please put that in your original question?

Answer (score 2):

I found how to config, now it works

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                                    <!--<classifier>jpa</classifier>-->
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>

                            <annotationProcessors>
                                <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            </annotationProcessors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <move todir="src/generated-sources/annotations"
                                      overwrite="true">
                                    <fileset dir="target/generated-sources/kapt/compile"/>
                                </move>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```